# How to capture Ctrl+Plus in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

How can I capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> in `QWidget::keyPressEvent`?

This is my current code (simplified):

```
void foo::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier)
    {
        switch (event->key())
        {
        case Qt::Key_Plus:
            // do something
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Which works, but only for <kbd>+</kbd> on the alphanumeric part of the keyboard. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> on the numeric keypad, it doesn't do anything.

Thank you

Comment: Well, add debug print to the handler, to print relevant fields of the `event`. What does it print when you press ctrl-plus on numeric keypad?

Answer (score 3):

After some debugging I found out that when a key is pressed on the numeric keypad, the `Qt::KeypadModifier` is added to event modifiers. So the simple solution is to add this to the if statement:

```
if (event->modifiers() == (Qt::ControlModifier | Qt::KeypadModifiers))
{
    // ...
```

Comment: Or just check for control being part of the modifiers
`if ((event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) != 0)`

Comment: For Python it's `Qt.KeypadModifier` (without the trailing 's').